# React CSSTransitionGroup issue when accessing offsetHeight of animated component during transition

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I ran into an issue while adding page transitions with React CSSTransitionGroup.
The problem is that animation stops working as expected if I access `offsetHeight` of the transitioned component while it still being animated.

Check out this example on Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgyBvO.

Page transitions work just fine. Now uncomment `console.log(this.refs.container.offsetHeight)` on line 12 and try again: it  skips the enter animation of the right page.